# Finding in certain projects only files with particular extensions when doing a project(ile) grep

Tags: projectile, project, source

I have projects where `*.nim` files are the source files and `*.js` files are the "compiled" files.

When I issue `projectile-grep` (or `project-find-regexp`) in these projects I get both source and compiled JavaScript files returned, but of course I do not want the JavaScript files.

How can I tell project(ile) *on a project-base* only to return the source files (here `*.nim` and `*.nims`)?

---

PS: I know I can give `projectile-grep` a glob with a prefix argument, but this is cumbersome to do for every search in this type of project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a per-project-base you can use the `.projectile` file to exclude JavaScript files. Create a `.projectile` file at the root of your project with a line like

```
-*.js
```

In Nim projects in particular you probably want to add all `nimcache` folders as well with

```
-nimcache
```

**Please note:** You need to switch to [hybrid or native indexing](https://docs.projectile.mx/projectile/2.3/configuration.html#project-indexing-method) in projectile. If you want to do this globally, just add for example

```
(setq projectile-indexing-method 'hybrid)
```

to your .emacs file or in your projectile use-package expression.

Answer (score 1):

The help for `projectile-grep` mentions the setting `projectile-grep-default-files`. I believe that you could use directory–local variables to set this to the correct value on a per–project basis, but I’ve not tried it myself.

Personally I use Ripgrep instead of grep. Ripgrep honors the `.gitignore` files that my projects all have, so it already ignores compiled files and concentrates on the correct source files.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in, but `projectile-grep-default-files` is a function. Changing this would be quite fiddling and for sure only the very last resort...

Comment: You’re right; I totally missed that.

Answer (score 1):

`C-u M-x project-find-regexp`.

See its documentation,

```
project-find-regexp is an interactive Lisp closure in ‘project.el.gz’.

(project-find-regexp REGEXP)

  Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 25.1.

Find all matches for REGEXP in the current project’s roots.
With C-u prefix, you can specify the directory
to search in, and the file name pattern to search for.  The
pattern may use abbreviations defined in ‘grep-files-aliases’,
e.g. entering ‘ch’ is equivalent to ‘*.[ch]’.  As whitespace
triggers completion when entering a pattern, including it
requires quoting, e.g. ‘M-x quoted-insert<space>’.
```